# What (preferably free) music software fits my purpose of downloading transcribed orchestral pieces and listening by instruments?

Tags: music

I'm seeking music software for Windows 10:

1. for whose format the most   orchestral pieces have been transcribed. I lack the time to notate or input notes myself. But most software's scanning accuracy, like [Photoscore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014HW35TY), are flawed:

> [I use and love Musescore, but I have never had any luck with the pdf import feature. I've even tried importing a pdf that was made by Musescore, and it didn't come close.](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/44lyxf/can_you_recommend_a_good_notation_software/czrhys6/)
>
> [Finale's recognition feature doesn't work really well](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/44lyxf/can_you_recommend_a_good_notation_software/czs7yax/)

2. that then allows to decompose the score and hear only some instrument(s).

E.g., I fancy downloading the score of some Xenakis piece and then listening to only what is played by instrument(s) that I choose.